# MathJax output dependent on reactive SelectInput choices

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, mathjax, selectinput

I am having trouble getting Rshiny to do what I want.

I would like the user to select an input from the SelectInput choices and based on that input I would like some Text output that is mathematical notation.

I have tried to implement this with withMathJax(), but I cannot seem to get the code right.
Here is some toy code illustrating what I have already:

######################################

```
ui <-navbarPage(title = "test",
                helpText("Here we select which parameters we want to include in our model"),
                selectInput("torchp",  
                label = h4("Torching Parameters"), 
                choices = list("One parameter", 
                               "Two parameters" ), 
 
                               selected = 1),
mainPanel(
textOutput("torchvalue")
)
)




server <- function(input, output) {

  withMathJax()
  
  torchp_input <- reactive({
    switch(input$torchp,
           "One parameter" = '$$q$$', 
            "Two parameters" = '$$q_m, q_f$$'
           )
    })
  
  output$torchvalue <- renderText({ 
   
    paste("You have selected", torchp_input())
  
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

###################################

The output I get does not recognise my mathematical notation.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic mathjax formula in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459729/dynamic-mathjax-formula-in-shiny)

Comment: Yes! This helped a lot Thanks.

The issue was which rendering function I used. 
In this instance you should use uiOutput and renderUI as follows:


 
In the ui put:
```
uiOutput("torchvalue")
```
In the server use:
```
output$torchvalue <- renderUI({    
     p( withMathJax("you have selected", torchp_input()))
    })

```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered an answer thanks to help in the comments by @Limey.

The issue was which rendering function I used.
In this instance you should use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` as follows:

1. In the UI put:

   ```
   uiOutput("torchvalue")
   ```
2. In the server use:

   ```
   output$torchvalue <- renderUI({ p( withMathJax("you have selected", torchp_input())) })
   ```